# Formed polyurethane blocks in attic

Tags: insulation, attic

We have formed (greenish coloured) polyurethane blocks leftover after a new building basement construction. My husband would like to throw these blocks into our attic for added insulation. is this a good idea? Any fire issues or any health or safety reasons  this should not be done?

Comment: If they're just "thrown" in, they probably won't do much good because they won't be arranged nicely in any way that will actually provide additional insulation. If they're stacked _neatly_, they might, but then they may compress the existing insulation thus reducing it's value, possibly by more than the added value of the blocks (AFAIK, poly-_urethane_ isn't usually used for insulation). Pics (including labeling) & dimensions of the blocks may help get you an answer.

Comment: @Freeman Regarding "AFAIK, poly-urethane isn't usually used for insulation": Closed cell and open cell spray foam is made from polyurethane in most cases I thought

Comment: That may be the case @UnhandledExcepSean. I only know of PU as a finish material, but I most certainly don't know it all.

Comment: If done right, using them as free extra, if poor insulation, is probably better than dumping them in the garbage.

Comment: The polyurethane is likely a fire hazard if not sealed behind a fire-resistant surface.